# Forcing divs to clear earlier and later floats

Tags: html, css

I have a defined div that, in execution, contains a heading paragraph class and an image class that allows "body" text to float up against said image. The problem is this: If the "body" text is not long enough to flow down past the image, the next instance of the div begins while floating against the image. I'm looking for a way to force each new instance of the div class to clear the previous floats and start on its own, flush against the container.

CSS:

```
.textChunk {
font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
font-size:20px;
display:block;
float:none;
}

.leftPic {
max-width:25%;
max-height:25%;
margin-right:10px;
float:left;
}

.rightPic {
max-width:25%;
max-height:25%;
margin-left:10px;
float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="textChunk">
    <img class="leftPic" src="images/img1.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div><br />
<div class="textChunk">
    <img class="leftPic" src="images/img2.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div><br />
<div class="textChunk">
    <img class="leftPic" src="images/img3.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Also, is there  a way to make the body text flow up against the picture AND continue to press up against the line of the picture's border even after the text passes the bottom of the image, so that it doesn't wrap around under the image?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you're asking; do you think you could provide a picture of the desired behavior as well as the existing behavior?

Comment: I think that its because you're not clearing the float, the parent div will take minimal height and won't recognize the floated image inside it, that's why everything will get mixed, so try `.textChunk:after{ content:""; display: block; clear: both;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `width:100%;` and/or `clear:both;` to your `.textChunk` div. Clear both means clear from floats on both sides.
If your `.textChunk` div is 100% wide than no float problems occur anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear:both` so that every new instance starts fresh. see this: http://jsfiddle.net/itz2k13/YGD6t/

```
.textChunk {
 font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
 font-size:20px;
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```